# How to get data from this objects num property using the name property as a selector

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to find the value of the `num` property of this object using the `name` property to select the right object from the `hashtagsl` array; so I get the right `num` value. I need to do this knowing only what the name in the element and userid are. The end goal is variable equal to the value of `num` in the specific object. Here is the code creating the object to show the structure of it. Thanks in advanced.

All code shown is server side.

```
Meteor.users.update({"_id": this.userId},{"$push":{"profile.hashtagsl": {name: newhashtag, num: 1}}})
```

edit

Here it is updating `inc`ing the `num` property. I need to get the value of `num` instead of updating it.

```
Meteor.users.update({"_id": this.userId, "profile.hashtagsl.name":hashi},{"$inc":{"profile.hashtagsl.$.num":1}});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the array element that matches `"name": newhashtag`? There is the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator for MongoDB but not sure if that projection method is supported in minimongo at present. Can always be done server side.

Comment: Don't have a meteor set-up to test on right now. But this should be just projection as in : `Meteor.users.find({ {"_id": this.userId, "profile.hashtagsl.name":hashi },{ "profile.hashtagsl.$": 1 });` That's the whole element from the array and not just one field, which is not possible in basic projection. `$set` operations are just the same as `$inc`.

Comment: Unfortunately Minimongo doesn't support that yet... :(

Comment: So which are you asking? How to **get** or how to **set**? You question and comments are conflicting.

Comment: @NeilLunn Both I want to get the value of `num` and set it to a variable so I can use it in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

`Meteor.users.findOne({'profile.hashtags1.name': somehashtag}).profile.hashtags1[index].num;`

As you can see, accessing nested properties in a MongoDB query can be done through the dot notation. Using findOne returns an object with a similar structure, and you can access the num property as you would any other javascript object.

Edit: I forgot to add that you have to specify an index for the hashtags, since the user document has an array of hashtags.

Comment: How would I specify an index of the object in the `hashtagsl` array  I don't have a way of knowing it. I will add an example of a similar thing to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Minimongo does not support the positional operator or elemMatch in projections yet. An alternative would be to iterate over the hashtags that are returned and find the one where the name matches, and then return the num of that.